# Killing explorer.exe through python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEmA8.png) I made a code that should kill explorer.exe, and then request typing password in cmd to restart service. But after killing explorer.exe rest of code doesn't continue, program just stops. I've tried to change the order of code, but it didn't work.(i use os.system('cmd /k "Taskkill/f /im explorer.exe"') to kill process.
the whole code is here

```
os.system('cmd /k "Taskkill/f /im explorer.exe"')
print("Sos button executed")

user_input = int(input("Enter password to unlock: "))
password = 2022

if user_input == password:
    os.system('cmd /k "start explorer"')
    exit()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by killing the explorer?

Comment: Explorer.exe is also hosting the Windows shell, this is not be the right way to do. It will kill the process, but it is not good. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need it as a button for some cases(nothing illegal)